Variable fonts with roundness axis
I'm looking for a sans serif font that features both rounded and square terminals, preferably a variable font. Google Fonts mentions that there is a variable font axis (ROND) for this purpose. Are there any fonts that actually feature this axis, other than this graphing font?
Alternatively, if there are any non-variable font superfamilies that have both a rounded and square sans-serif, that could work as well.
I'm sourcing from Google Fonts and Adobe Fonts, but am interested if such fonts exist anywhere.

Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you checked the list at Google Fonts?.  Looks like Wavefront is the only Google font that uses this. Not sure if Adobe publishes a list like this, but you can check the variable font axes for each font. This might mean going through each variable font to find out.  As of today, they list 153 sans-serif variable font families, so not that many.  The difficulty in answering a question like this is that it would probably involve doing extensive research.

I've checked Google Fonts. I fully realize the potential amount of research needed. That's why I'm here. In the case that someone has already found such fonts, I don't have to do that a lot of that research myself.

well, you may get lucky with an answer of course. There are fonts such as Arial, Helvetica, and Bebas Neue which have normal and rounded variants. These aren't variable fonts though
